# Will I get to experience the whole storyline as a new WoW player?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

WoW has had gone through several expansions now. If I start playing as a new subscriber at this time, will I still get to experience the storyline since its first release or will I miss out all the previous storyline?

Comment: I'd consider rewording your title. If you'll enjoy it, is not something we can answer.

Comment: The linked question answers this pretty well Jake.  The Cataclysm update replaced the entirety of the original world, and while pieces of some original quests remain, most of the original storyline was removed in favor of story dealing with Cataclysm or the new hostilities between Alliance / Horde.

Comment: Summarizing the linked question, most the story in Classic is gone now, but you can play through the story of every expansion.  But since WoW is a MMO, the world as a whole is already caught up.  Unlike other games, it doesn't matter if you do the quests or not, the story moves forward.  The easiest way to catch up on the story is to start playing then use your friend google to answer any lore questions you might have

Comment: No, the game seems to have changed constantly in small ways, improvements to make things better, things changed quite drastically when the cataclysm expansion was released. As I understand it most of the old quests were repurposed to fit with the changes to the world that came about with the cataclysm, so in a way it's mostly still there. If you have time you can do every single quest, though you might want to disable level progression so that you can experience the difficulty as it was intended by the designers.